# How string item order in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran a Cypher query with the clause:

> ORDER BY xxx DESC

where `xxx` is a string, like `["Coyote"," Eastern Coyote"]`. I want it ordered with first alphabet ASC, like this: `[" Eastern Coyote","Coyote"]`.
but the outcome is still this: `["Coyote"," Eastern Coyote"]`.

FYI: i asked chatgpt,it said order in neo4j is depends on alphabet's unicode, but it still not make sense, cause "E" is Larger than "C"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... The query uses `DESC` which will sort words by *descending* alphanumerical order indeed. If you want the ascending order, replacing `DESC` with `ASC` will just work, or what am I missing?

Comment: you are sorting the list and NOT the items on the list. You need to rearrange each item on the list instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the items on the list in below examples:

1. Using UNWIND and COLLECT

```
    WITH  [ "Coyote"," Eastern Coyote"]  as lst
    UNWIND lst as l
    WITH l ORDER by l
    RETURN  collect(l) as sorted_lst
```

2. Using apoc function sort

```
    WITH  [ "Coyote"," Eastern Coyote"]  as lst
    RETURN apoc.coll.sort(lst) as sorted_lst
```

Result:

```
╒════════════════════════════╕
│"sorted_lst"                │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│[" Eastern Coyote","Coyote"]│
└────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you made some major mistakes:

1. `["Coyote"," Eastern Coyote"]` is a **list** of strings, not a string.
2. `ORDER BY xxx DESC` sorts in **descending** order, not ascending.
3. You said:

   > ... still not make sense, cause "E" is Larger than "C"

   But the string " Eastern Coyote" actually starts with a **space** character, so you should have been comparing " " to "C". The " " character has a lower lexical value than "C". Therefore, `["Coyote"," Eastern Coyote"]` is the correct answer after sorting the list items in **descending** order.

You need to double-check your string values to remove extraneous spaces.

Also, to return a list of the strings from `xxx` in **ascending** order (which is the default order), you can use this snippet:

```
...
UNWIND xxx AS y
WITH y ORDER BY y
RETURN COLLECT(y) AS result
```

Or, if you really want to return the list in **descending** order:

```
...
UNWIND xxx AS y
WITH y ORDER BY y DESC
RETURN COLLECT(y) AS result
```